# COM Aggregation - Delete Outer Component but retain Inner

Tags: com, aggregation

I have some theoretical questions about COM aggregation:

1. Is it possible to delete the outer component but retain the Inner Component? (I suppose not, but I am not 100% sure.)
2. Is it possible that an Inner Component is aggregated by two different Outer Components (directly)?
3. If the answer to the other two question is no, then is it correct that 'COM aggregation' is rather composition in UML terms than aggregation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer 1, no.  The inner object increments the outer object's reference count when its `IUnknown::QueryInterface` runs successfully for a non-`IUnknown` IID.  Essentially, if the inner object is alive, so is the outer object, even if no external entity holds a reference to the outer object.  This must be so, because any `QueryInterface`, `AddRef` and `Release` performed on the inner object's non-`IUnknown` interface pointers must delegate to the outer object.

To answer 2, no.  The inner object has no way to know from which object it is being invoked from, and even if there was, it would make identity break.  For instance, in COM the only reliable object identity check is if two `IUnknown` interface pointers are the same or not, but everyone assumes that if any two, possibly non-`IUnknown`, interface pointers are the same, they're from the same object (there's no guarantee the other way around, two non-`IUnknown` interface pointers, even of the same type, might be different and refer to the same object).

To answer 3, COM aggregation is a special case of composition, where instead of implementing the intercepted interfaces with redirecting or wrapping methods, we return direct interface pointers from the inner object.  This optimization is more relevant when you have many composed objects.  It should not be the first approach to composition, as you lose control and some restrictions apply, e.g. you can't wrap objects provided to or returned by the inner objects, no pre- and post-processing, the outer object and the inner object should not overlap in functionality (e.g. if the outer object has a parent object according to some definition of parent, the inner object should not have a different parent under the same definition, or it should be completely ignorant of such a parent object; same for child objects), etc.

Answer (score 2):

When you create an aggregated COM object, you are providing an outer interface at instantiation time, and it cannot be changed later. This is eventually a "no" to the first two questions.